# How to add a custom panel to particle properties?

Tags: python, scripting, particles, add-on, panel

I'm trying to add a new panel to show up in the particles section of the *Properties Editor*.

```
class CudaParticlePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "CudaParticle_Panel"
    bl_label = "CudaParticle"
    bl_category = "SYSTEM"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "PARTICLES"

    def draw(self, context):    
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text= "CudaParticals Properties:")
        self.layout.label(text="CudaParticle")
```

I don't get any errors or warnings when running the code but my panel does not show up. Can anyone please explain different locations of the UI and how to put a panel there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the class to use it.

Also `bl_context = "PARTICLES"` should be replaced by `bl_context = "particle"`

Here's the complete script

```
import bpy


class CudaParticlePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "CudaParticle_Panel"
    bl_label = "CudaParticle"
    bl_category = "SYSTEM"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "particle"

    def draw(self, context):    
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text= "CudaParticals Properties:")
        self.layout.label(text="CudaParticle")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CudaParticlePanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CudaParticlePanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```